# How do I get Microsoft Access to recognize my date field on my form?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, adp

I have form in Microsoft Access with a date field.  Every time I enter a date in the field and click the Print button the "Enter Parameter Value" dialog pops up.  This means the date in being entered twice.  I want to enter the date in the form and when I click the Print button the report should open up instead of the dialog box.  How do I get the date field to be recognized by the procedure the first time without having to enter it again?  I believe the project was created in Microsoft Access 2000 but, I'm opening the project in Microsoft Access 2010.

Here is the code in the procedure:

```
SELECT      ISNULL([LEVEL OF SERVICE], 'Total') AS SERVICES, ID AS Total
FROM          dbo.Table1
WHERE      (servicedate BETWEEN @begin AND @end) AND (servicedate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ISNULL([LEVEL OF SERVICE], 'Total'), ID
```

Comment: You will have to share your secret code.

Comment: Here is the code behind the procedure: SELECT      ISNULL([LEVEL OF SERVICE], 'Total') AS SERVICES, ID AS Total
FROM          dbo.Table1
WHERE      (servicedate BETWEEN @begin AND @end) AND (servicedate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ISNULL([LEVEL OF SERVICE], 'Total'), ID

Comment: Is this an ADP project? -- There are no references to a form field in this query.

Comment: Yes, it is. The form has a begin date, end date, and a print button.  I enter a date into the begin date field and end date field then click the print button.  The report should come up but, instead I get "Enter Parameter Value" for the begin and end date.  I want form to recognize the dates the first time I enter them.

Comment: I found the problem.  I needed to add the parameters as the "input Parameters" property on the report.

Comment: Cool. Be sure to include this information, should you ask another question about this project, because hardly anybody uses ADP anymore.